# Configuring and injecting Grails services

Tags: grails, service, dependency-injection

Grails 2.4.5 here. I did a `grails create-service com.example.service.Simple` which created a `SimpleService` for me, which I then modified to look like so:

```
class SimlpeService {
    SimpleClient simpleClient

    Buzz doSomething(String derp) {
        // ...
        Fizz fizz = simpleClient.doSomething(derp)
        // ...
        fizz.asBuzz()
    }
}
```

I can now "inject" controllers with `SimpleService` like so:

```
class MyController {
    SimpleService simpleService

    def index() {
        // etc...
    }
}
```

But how do I configure/wire `SimpleService` with the correct `SimpleClient` instance. Let's pretend `SimpleClient` is typically built like so:

```
SimpleClient simpleClient = SimpleClientBuilder
    .withURL('http://simpleclientdev.example.com/simple')
    .withAuth('luggageCombo', '12345')
    .isOptimized(true)
    .build()
```

Depending on what environment I'm in, I may want my `SimpleClient` instance to connect to `simpleclientdev.example.com`, `simpleclientqa.example.com`, or even `simpleclient.example.com`. Also, I may use different auth credentials, and I might/might not want it to be "optimized", etc. The point is: **How do I inject the `SimpleService` with a `SimpleClient` instance?**

Comment: Why not create a service that configures and returns a `SimpleClient` according to how you have it configured for your environment through your config (e.g. `Config.groovy`)? That's the way I'd approach it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Java's [PostConstruct](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) annotation on one of your method in your service to do the stuff you want. From the docs:

> The PostConstruct annotation is used on a method that needs to be
>   executed after dependency injection is done to perform any
>   initialization.

**SimpleService.groovy**

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct

class SimlpeService {

    private SimpleClient simpleClient

    def grailsApplication

    @PostConstruct
    void postConstruct() {
        def config = grailsApplication.config.client.data

        SimpleClient simpleClient = SimpleClientBuilder
            .withURL(config.url)
            .withAuth('luggageCombo', config.username)
            .isOptimized(config.optimized)
            .build()
    }

    Buzz doSomething(String derp) {
        // ...
        Fizz fizz = simpleClient.doSomething(derp)
        // ...
        fizz.asBuzz()
    }
}
```

So, Grails or Spring will call this method `postConstruct()` automatically when all the dependencies (in this case `grailsApplication`) for this service are resolved and any of the service method is invoked.
This has been taken care that that method **must** invoke before you access any field member or method of the `SimpleService`.

Now, everything is already configured like you mentioned that you may need to call different URL with different credential, just you have to define them in your `Config.groovy` as:

```
environments {
    development {
        client {
            data {
                url = "simpleclientdev.example.com"
                username = "test"
                optimized = false
            }
        }
    }
    production {
        client {
            data {
                url = "simpleclient.example.com"
                username = "johndoe"
                optimized = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now when you do `run-app` with development mode and calling `simpleService.doSomething()` in your example controller will automatically hit the `simpleclientdev.example.com` URL with test credential and when you deploy it using production environment, the same `simpleService.doSomething()` method will hit `simpleclient.example.com` with `optimized` set to `true`.

**Update**
The key point here based on your question is that we will not be injecting different instances of `SimpleService` since services are singleton by default. Instead we are changing the value's associated with the service based on the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to understand a bit more about how to leverage Spring maybe?
[Grails Spring Docs](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/spring.html)

You can also do things like so in your Service class

```
 @PostConstruct
void init() {
    //configure variables, etc here ...
    log.debug("Initialised some Service...")
}
```